# use a callback on an animated button class

Tags: flutter, dart

So I have this button which animates `onPressed` but I want to use it as a class, and call it as a widget.

I need also a `VoidCallback` on it so I can actually do something with the button when I press it for example Navigation or calling a function.

how to make it animate and accept a callback. So basically I need 2 callbacks on this class

```
class AnimatedShadowButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final double height;
  final double width;
  final double finalHeight;
  final double finalWidth;
  final Curve curve;
  final VoidCallback onClick;
  final Widget buttonText;

  const AnimatedShadowButton(
      {Key key,
      this.height,
      this.width,
      this.finalHeight,
      this.finalWidth,
      this.curve,
      this.onClick,
      this.buttonText})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AnimatedShadowButtonState createState() => _AnimatedShadowButtonState();
}

class _AnimatedShadowButtonState extends State<AnimatedShadowButton> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    buttonHeight = widget.height;
    buttonWidth = widget.width;
    super.initState();
  }

  double buttonHeight;
  double buttonWidth;

  void aniButo() {

    setState(() {
      buttonHeight = buttonHeight == widget.height
          ? widget.finalHeight
          : widget.height;
      buttonWidth = buttonWidth == widget.width
          ? widget.finalWidth
          : widget.width;
    });

  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      curve: widget.curve,
      width: buttonWidth,
      height: buttonHeight,
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () => aniButo(),
        child: widget.buttonText,
        elevation: 30.0,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is how I call it

```
 AnimatedShadowButton(
              height: 60.0,
              width: 80.0,
              finalHeight: 120.0,
              finalWidth: 180.0,
              curve: Curves.easeInBack,
              buttonText: Text("something"),
//             onClick: ()  //Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (cxt) => Card())),
            ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit `aniButo` method

```
void aniButo() {
  widget.onClick();
  /* ... other code */
}
```

or add something like that:

```
child: RaisedButton(
    onPressed: () {
      aniButo();
      widget.onClick();
    },
    child: widget.buttonText,
    elevation: 30.0,
  )
```

And on creating button:

```
AnimatedShadowButton(
          height: 60.0,
          width: 80.0,
          finalHeight: 120.0,
          finalWidth: 180.0,
          curve: Curves.easeInBack,
          buttonText: Text("something"),
          onClick: ()  { 
            Navigator.of(context)
              .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (cxt) => Card()))
          },
        ),
```